# i want list a part of list and make a list of one attribute

Tags: python

i have a list it has name and number I want to make one list of name and list number

```
d = [("Alex", 9), ("Amir", 10), ("Kevin", 11)]
```

i want list `Alex` , `Amir` , `Kevin`
what I have do help please

Answer (score 2):

Use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
l = [x[0] for x in d]
# l = ['Alex', 'Amir', 'Kevin']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = [("Alex", 9), ("Amir", 10), ("Kevin", 11)]
print([t[0] for t in d])
# ['Alex', 'Amir', 'Kevin']
print([t[1] for t in d])
# [9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Im new sorry for problemes

Comment: No apology is necessary.  As you can see from the answers, there's more than one way to achieve what you're looking for. I learned how to use the zip function thanks to arun n a. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the zip function

```
d = [("Alex", 9), ("Amir", 10), ("Kevin", 11)]
name_t, number_t = zip(*d)
print(name_t)
print(number_t)
```

Output

```
('Alex', 'Amir', 'Kevin')
(9, 10, 11)
```

Change this tuple name and number to list

```
print(list(name_t))
print(list(number_t))
```

Output:

```
['Alex', 'Amir', 'Kevin']
[9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: i want to make it list but Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First I'm going to start of by declaring my variables. Then I'm going to create a list comprehension and a function to put the information into the needed format:

```
d = [("Alex", 9), ("Amir", 10), ("Kevin", 11)]
d_names = []
d_numbers = []

def my_function(a, b):
    d_names.append(a)
    d_numbers.append(b)

[my_function(x[0], x[1]) for x in d]
print(d_names, d_numbers)
#  ['Alex', 'Amir', 'Kevin'] [9, 10, 11]
```

Since the code in my_function can be put on one line, we don't need my_function. We can put it all in the list comprehension:

```
d = [("Alex", 9), ("Amir", 10), ("Kevin", 11)]
d_names = []
d_numbers = []

[(d_names.append(x[0]), d_numbers.append(x[1])) for x in d]

print(d_names)
print(d_numbers)
# ['Alex', 'Amir', 'Kevin']
# [9, 10, 11]
```